# Frequency in RL Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, inductor, frequency, homework

A 24.0-mH inductor, with internal resistance of 24.0 Ohms, is connected to a 110-V rms source. If the average power dissipated in the circuit is 50.0 W, what is the frequency?

So I tried using X<sub>L</sub>=2πfL and X<sub>R</sub>=R.

First I used P=I<sup>2</sup>R-->50W=(I<sup>2</sup>)(24)-->I=1.4434A then I used Ohms laws V=IR-->110V=(1.4434)((2π)f(0.016H+24ohms)) and solved for f. But this doesnt seem like the answer.

Any ideas on how to solve the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$I=\sqrt{\dfrac{P}{R}}\$   = Apparent current.

What is ω?  \$I=\dfrac{V}{Z}=\dfrac{V}{\sqrt{R^2+{ωL}^2}}\$

so \$\sqrt{\dfrac{P}{R}}=\dfrac{V}{\sqrt{R^2+{ωL}^2}}\$ 
and

\$\dfrac{P}{R}=\dfrac{V^2}{R^2+ωL^2}\$ and

solve for ω

Answer (score 0):

We know that:

$$\text{P}_{\space\text{in}}=\overline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot\overline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot\cos\left(\varphi\right)\tag1$$

So, when we have a series circuit with a resistor and inductor we can write (assuming that the source has no phase):

$$\text{P}_{\space\text{in}}=\overline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot\frac{\overline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\cdot\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)\right)=$$
$$\overline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot\frac{\overline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)^2}}=\overline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}^2\cdot\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\tag2$$

So:

$$50.0=110^2\cdot\frac{24.0}{24.0^2+\left(2\pi\cdot\text{f}\cdot24\cdot10^{-3}\right)^2}\space\implies\space$$
$$\text{f}=\frac{1750}{\pi}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\approx454.823134052978\tag3$$